# REST API add barcodes methods

Tags: rest, api

My task is to make a REST API.

I have a product table (products) and table barcodes (product_barcode) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeIkI.png)

What will the methods of accessing the API look like?

While there should be a method for pulling products with barcode and mom updates and additions.

In my view, it looks like this

Withdraw items with bearcodes - `'GET api/products/barcodes'`

Bulk add barcodes - `'POST api/products/{productId}/barcodes'`

Bulk add barcodes - `'POST api/products/{productId}/barcodes'`

Bulk barcode changes - `'PATCH api/products/{productId}/barcodes`'

Delete one barcode - `'DELETE api/products/{productId}/barcodes/{barcodeId}'`

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the barcode is an element on the item, so you wouldn't need `GET api/products/barcodes` -- rather if you wanted to list items with barcodes, you would generally make the barcode a field that could be returned as part of the product list:

```
GET api/products?fields=_id,name,desc,barcode
```

Likewise, adding barcodes is just adding a field to an existing product (or `POST` with all fields if you're creating a new product):

```
PUT api/products/{product_id}

{"barcode":"1234567890"}
```

This changes a bit if any one product could have multiple barcodes - but usually each barcode has a specific purpose, so you could have `barcode_UPC`, `barcode_SKU`, and so on.

```
PUT api/products/{product_id}

{"barcode_UPC":"1234567890", "barcode_SKU":"774747774"}
```

Comment: Is that really a usecase for the API?  It violates REST principles, because it's not an update to a resource - it's a batch update to many resources.  Generally, bulk uploads can be done in serial (or parallel) as a one-time update (where one time means occasional) to product.  It seems unlikely that you'd be uploading barcodes without uploading a product as well.